# Count ocurrences in index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                      brand1   brand2  brand3
survey                  22       33      12                    
clothes                 19       22      19
shoes                   34       12      15
```

What I'd like to do is count how many clothes I have and how many shoes in total, not taking into consideration the categories. I'm not sure how to do this since "survey" is not a column.

I basically want this:

```
survey
clothes         100
shoes           100
```

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: `I'm not sure how to do this since "survey" is not a column`, what do you mean by that? Please make the question a little clearer

Comment: `df.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: well, thank you @QuangHoang that pretty much did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
df.sum(axis = 1)
```

This should give the sum of values of the rows, then to display you can use a dictionary with keys as the survey column names, and value as the df.sum's values (maybe after storing it in a list).

Comment: That worked! Would you happen to know how to plot the results with seaborn? Because since it's not a column, it gives me an error when I try to put it in the x axis. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Ah sorry man, no idea how to do that :/, maybe ask a different question and someone will answer.